# Adding random weighted point

Tags: python, math, random, point

Let's say I have a blank canvas with 2 red points in it.

Is there an algorithm to randomly add a point in the canvas but in a way where it's more bias to the red points with a supplied radius?

Here's a crude image as an example:
[image]

Even though this question is for Python it really applies for any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Select first point or second point randomly, then generate some distribution with single scale parameter in polar coordinates, then shift by
center point position. Select some reasonable radial distribution (gaussian in the code below, exponential or Cauchy might work as well)

```
import math
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def select_point():
    p = random.random()
    if p < 0.5:
        return 0
    return 1

def sample_point(R):
    """
    Sample point inpolar coordinates
    """
    phi = 2.0 * math.pi * random.random() # angle
    r   = R * random.gauss(0.0, 1.0)      # might try different radial distribution, R*random.expovariate(1.0)

    return (r * math.cos(phi), r * math.sin(phi))

def sample(R, points):
    idx = select_point()

    x, y = sample_point(R)

    return (x + points[idx][0], y + points[idx][1])

R = 1.0
points = [(7.1, 3.3), (4.8, -1.4)]

random.seed(12345)

xx = []
yy = []
cc = []

xx.append(points[0][0])
xx.append(points[1][0])

yy.append(points[0][1])
yy.append(points[1][1])

cc.append(0.8)
cc.append(0.8)

for k in range(0, 50):
    x, y = sample(R, points)
    xx.append(x)
    yy.append(y)
    cc.append(0.3)

plt.scatter(xx, yy, c=cc)
plt.show()
```

Picture

[image]