# Generate random (x,y) points for K-means clustering

Tags: python, random, coordinates, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to randomly generate a bunch of points for a graph in python to test k-means clustering algorithm with. Here's my code.

```
N = 100
random_x0 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
random_x1 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
random_x2 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) + (np.random.randint(0,100) * np.random.randint(1,4))
```

As you might imagine, each set of `random_x[index]` coordinates is matched with it's y counterpart.

```
(random_x0, random_y0), (random_x1, random_y1), (random_x2, random_y2)
```

[image: image of expected resulting distribution]

Since I am testing a clustering algorithm, I want my data points to be SOMEWHAT clustered...but this seems like too much. I tried to add a random number from 1-100, then multiple that by a random number from 1-4....what am I doing wrong to get such consistent random results?

Comment: The two trailing terms (the `randint` calls) are serving only to *shift* the clusters, not spread them out.  If you want to spread them out, multiply your random vector (from `randn`) by some static scaling factor -- maybe something like: `random_x0 = scale * np.random.randn(N)`  The farthest a point will be from 0,0 will be *scale* away.  [The note here might help](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

Comment: @jedwards The standard deviation of a Gaussian distribution (`scale` in this case) is not the same as the maximal distance of a point from its mean.

Comment: @dorverbin I linked the doc but didn't even read it, assuming it worked like [rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand), but over a wider interval.  Good catch.  (For clarity: The last sentence of my first comment isn't true, the rest still holds)

Comment: YOu might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265844/adding-random-weighted-point/47266653#47266653

Answer (score 1):

`randn` is a random gaussian variable with zero mean and variance equal to one. In order to generate a Gaussian variable with mean `m` and standard deviation `s` one would do `m + s*randn()`. Since you do `randn(N) + constant` you basically create gaussian variables with standard deviation one and mean equal to `constant`. Now `constant` is given by a random variable that can vary from 0 to 297, i.e. the spread in centroids is much larger than the variance. You probably want a centroid (i.e. mean) spread that's a few standard deviations. You can also pass multiple mean and std.dev. values to `random.normal` for example:

```
np.random.normal(loc=[0, 1, 2], scale=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0], size=(N, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to decide what kind of distribution is wanted. Let's say its Gauss, so we can use [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.gauss).

I't create a function which generates a 2D point with Gauss distribution:

```
def generate_point(mean_x, mean_y, deviation_x, deviation_y):
    return random.gauss(mean_x, deviation_x), random.gauss(mean_y, deviation_y)
```

Then, decide how many clusters, how many points per cluster and which deviation to use for clusters and points within a cluster. For example:

```
cluster_mean_x = 100
cluster_mean_y = 100
cluster_deviation_x = 50
cluster_deviation_y = 50
point_deviation_x = 5
point_deviation_y = 5

number_of_clusters = 5
points_per_cluster = 50
```

Then, generate cluster centres:

```
cluster_centers = [generate_point(cluster_mean_x,
                                  cluster_mean_y,
                                  cluster_deviation_x,
                                  cluster_deviation_y)
                   for i in range(number_of_clusters)]
```

Then generate the actual points for each cluster:

```
points = [generate_point(center_x,
                         center_y,
                         point_deviation_x,
                         point_deviation_y)
          for center_x, center_y in cluster_centers
          for i in range(points_per_cluster)]
```